# jQuery blink text for 1 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set blink in 1 minutes and then after that unset the blink on my jQuery function below?

```
var html = '<table>';
for(var i in list)
{
    var tClass = list[i];

    if(jsonStr.currentTime == times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+":00")
    {
        $("#audio").html('<audio style="width: 100%;" class="audioDemo" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload"><source src="assets/audio/alarm2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
        $(".audioDemo").trigger("play");

        tClass += " blinker";
    }

    html += '<td class="box"><span class="'+ tClass+'">'+ list[i]+'<div class="timeValue">'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+'</div></span></td>';
}
html += '</table>';
document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;

$('.blinker').blink();
```

The current function, it will blink only 1 time.

What I want is the blink is set for 1 minute and then clear it after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving this, is by using `setTimeOut()`: [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

In your case, you could add this to your code:

```
setTimeout(function() {

$(".blinker").unblink();

},60000)
```

The `60000` stands for 60 times 1000 milliseconds.

For the one time blinking: try adding a timespan:

```
$(".blinker").blink(500);
```

Edit: After some major debugging via StackOverflow chat, we found that there were some more issues with the code, preventing the solution above to work. In the end we solved it all. But the main answer for the question is in the solution above.

Comment: Blink is still only one time

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Edited.

Answer (score 4):

[Blink plugin](https://antiyes.com/2009/08/24/jquery-blink-plugin/) has the method to stop blinking so you can use this along with `setTimeout`

```
$('.blinker').blink();

setTimeout( function(){
   $('.blinker').unblink();
}, 60*1000);
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.blinker').blink();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.blinker').unblink();
  }, 60 * 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://johnboker.github.io/jquery.blink.js"></script>
<div class="blinker">This line will blink</div>
<div class="noblinker">This line won't blink</div>
```

Comment: Hi... blink is still only 1 time

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I have attached a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS here, as this can be done in CSS alone. In the example below the blink effect takes 1 second to complete, and will occur 60 times:

```css
span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blinking 1s linear 60;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  from, 49.9% { opacity: 0; }
  50%, to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<span>Blink for 1 min...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` function ( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp ). After 1 minute use `clearInterval` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: if you know it only happens once, `setTimeOut` is a better alternative than `setInterval`.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval